# How to get last element when scraping with requests_html

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I try to **scrape** something with `requests_html`.
There is several div tag that contains the class name that i want to scrap.
I know that you can select just the first element with `first=True` as it is:

```
driver.html.find(".company__item-value", first=True)
```

But how can I do if i only want to select the last element of the class `company__item` ?

[image]

Comment: find all elements and get last one  `find(...)[-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all elements and get last one `find(...)[-1]`